# DVI-HDMI cable increases temperature after plug in video card with 7 degrees celsius

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I have bought a DVI-HDMI cable (Video cart - Monitor) for my monitor, that was using a VGA cable.

My config is dual monitor: Samsung S22C00 + Samsung Syncmaster 225 BW (configure to run on same resolution and hertz like S22C00 [1920x1080*60hz]) + NVIDIA GTX 260.

After pluging in the new cable the DVI-HDMI cable to my S22C00 I have noticed an increase in temperature from 51 C to 58 C, a 7 degree celsius in the temp.

Is this normal, how can I overcome it?

EDIT

After following advice from `Psycogeek` I have installed `GPU-Z` and have the following data

VGA Cable:

[image]

HDMI Cable:

[image]

Graph Card

[image]

Comment: Hmmmm....seems to me that your video card would be doing more work with HDMI over simple VGA thus with more work, more heat.  I don't necessarily see a problem here.

Comment: Should not be opposite? Do less work and have better quality and performance.

Comment: Check the "clock rate" that your gpu is running at , AMD (for example) the presence of a second monitor alone the software kicks up the speed some (at the low). Use GPU-Z program to see things like that. How that differs from the analog , I do not know, you were at the exact same resolutions with the analog VGA?  If it is the speed and stepping of the GPU item, potentially you could set that manually. (I set manually here to stop it).  . In the question you could supply  specifications of the hardware a little more clearly.

Comment: Ok, I have installed GPU-Z and cleared up this, for some reason all the clocks are getting OC'ed. Is there anyway to limit this?

Comment: It all looks completly normal, for some reasons there is a bit more work to do, and the clocks all look fine. Overclocking tools or even the manufactures own software can not only overclock, but "underclock", and set stuff manually just to control it. If a person wanted to make that effort they could, but it is not nessisary. I have no experince with nvidia, but i do know there are at least 3 tools that could be used to control it, like rivatuner, msi afterburner, and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you think this is unusual?!

Check out the CPU rates with both cables, that is likely to show you what is working harder. But I'm not at all surprised. For starters, as I understand it, HDMI has enforced DRM thanks to those "wonderful" folk at MPAA/RIAA.

Have you also made sure that you have the latest drivers installed for everything?

Comment: I have all the drivers up to date.